# Why isn't the mutate function creating the new column?

Tags: r, tidyverse

r beginner here.

I'm trying to create a new column with the following code:

```
data %>% mutate(age_cat = if_else(suspect_age %in% 0:14, "Under 15", if_else(suspect_age %in% 15:24, "15-24", ifelse(suspect_age %in% 25:34, "25-34", ifelse(suspect_age %in% 35:44, "35-44", ifelse(suspect_age %in% 45:54, "45-54", ifelse(suspect_age %in% 55:64, "55-64", "65 & over")))))))
```

But the new column isn't actually being created, why is that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does any error message pop up?

Comment: No, apparently i just needed to assign it. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: For this kind of operation, you can consider using `cut()` instead of the tedious `if_else()` or `case_when()`

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, you can use `case_when` instead of all the `ifelse` statements. If on the left of `~` is `TRUE`, then execute what is on the right of `~`. With the new column, you just need to assign it to a variable. Or if you just need to quickly view the dataframe, then you can add on `%>% view`.

```
library(tidyverse)

results <- data %>% 
  mutate(age_cat = case_when(suspect_age %in% 0:14 ~ "Under 15",
                                    suspect_age %in% 15:24 ~ "15-24",
                                    suspect_age %in% 25:34 ~ "25-34",
                                    suspect_age %in% 35:44 ~ "35-44",
                                    suspect_age %in% 45:54 ~ "45-54",
                                    suspect_age %in% 55:64 ~ "55-64",
                                    TRUE ~ "65 & over"))
```

**Output**

```
results

   suspect_age   age_cat
1           12  Under 15
2           77 65 & over
3           21     15-24
4           36     35-44
5           58     55-64
6           11  Under 15
7           74 65 & over
8           92 65 & over
9           32     25-34
10          31     25-34
```

Or another option is to use `cut`:

```
data %>%
  mutate(age_cat = cut(suspect_age, breaks = c(0, seq(14, 64, 10), 110),
                       labels = c("Under 15", "15-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65 & over"),
                       include.lowest = TRUE))
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(suspect_age = c(12L, 77L, 21L, 36L, 58L, 11L, 
74L, 92L, 32L, 31L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: I decided to just use a new line of code and move on, but with your code, I get the error "Error in suspect_age %in% 0:14 : object 'suspect_age' not found"

Comment: Oh, no it actually worked fine as it was. I get the error when I try using select

Comment: I tried it and it just didn't show anything (no errors either).

Comment: It doesn't show it when I run the code, but I viewed the whole dataframe and 'age_cat' was the only column that appeared, as though the rest had been cut

Comment: I'm hoping that by using select, i'll immediately be shown 'age_cat', but nothing occurs. However, when I do 'view(data)', 'age_cat' is the only column available, as if the actual dataframe had been altered and the rest of the columns had been removed. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @skarbietae If you are assigning the output to a variable, then it won't print anything to the console (if that's what you are hoping for). But you could always add `%>% print()` at the end, and it will still assign to variable, but also print to the console.

Comment: It prints the whole data, but I only want 'age_cat'. On another note, I really appreciate you trying to help me, you're very patient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you are expecting the new column to be present in `data` after you run that command.

In that case, you need to assign it.

`data <- data %>% mutate(age_cat = if_else(suspect_age %in% 0:14, "Under 15", if_else(suspect_age %in% 15:24, "15-24", ifelse(suspect_age %in% 25:34, "25-34", ifelse(suspect_age %in% 35:44, "35-44", ifelse(suspect_age %in% 45:54, "45-54", ifelse(suspect_age %in% 55:64, "55-64", "65 & over")))))))`

Comment: Thank you! One more thing, if you don't mind: when I try selecting the new column in the same line of code, it doesn't show it?

Comment: If the name of the object is the same and you just need to overwrite it, you can also use `%<>%` from `magrittr` as an alternative (with the caveat that's slightly harder to spot in with some long code)